# How to show facebook group wall/posts on the website in a feed

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-group

I am new here, I have read through all possible solutions to this and I can't find anything that answers our problem. I am an admin for a facebook **group** and we want to show the wall posts on a feed for the charities website. We have allowed anyone to see the posts on the facebook group settings. However, we cannot get it to work on the website feed to show the wall entries.

One problem maybe that no one has the original settings when the group was set up. There are now group two admins but both admins don't have any setup logins to see data from the group. Can we change this so we can get all the data that is available? We don't have any access to group users and data that is usual with pages so I think we are missing something major here.

The group is https://www.facebook.com/groups/borntoosoonkh/

Any help for a workaround on the access issue and also if it is possible to show wall posts from a group on a website feed. 
Really hope you all have brilliant ideas. 
Thank you for reading and your time.

one last thing, please.......I know that you cannot like a post unless you are a member of the group but I also can't find a join button for people to request membership.

Comment: What do you mean for "a feed", an RSS/Atom feed?

Answer (score 5):

You can programmatically access the wall posts of a group, but you'll need an access_token, acquired from a Facebook Connect button.

For an example, see the [Graph Api Debug Console: group Born too soon](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=23239134181/feed)

[image]

Comment: Hi are you able to give an update to this with the recent changes to v2.12 of the API? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

read this it will get you there
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
$session,
'GET',
'/groups/feed'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
// handle the result
```

Comment: im sorry but i just found this i think its exactly what you want with a few mods of course   http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2011/php/adding-a-facebook-news-status-feed-to-a-website/

Comment: Hi are you able to give an update to this with the recent changes to v2.12 of the API? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am currently researching the same problem. You have to find a way to get an access token without a specific user. How to do this? Still working at it. But like the user above said get it from the Gragh API explorer on the facebook developers site, problem is it times out.

What I did was create a facebook app. Use this site below as a guide... 
http://ranacse05.wordpress.com/2011/02/04/show-facebook-group-wall-on-web-site/

its old but it should bring you up to speed. And you can have something like the code below some where:

```
$token = $access_token;     //$access_token is created in facebook app
$token ='?access_token='.$access_token;  //append '?access_token field' from included php file
$url1 = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$group_id.$token;
$des = json_decode(file_get_contents($url1));
```

Answer (score 0):

[Wallflux.com](http://wallflux.com) provides feeds for facebook groups, not sure about your question about the join button, though.

warning, im affiliated with Wallflux